# open ldap registration with Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, authentication, ldap, openldap

The docs are very clear on how to authenticate against open LDAP with ZF. But, I failed to find the docs on how to register new users, delete users and update users (change password) using ZF on Open LDAP.
Any good docs out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [ZF ldap API](http://www.framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.ldap.html), might help you.